# Is there a way to customize http response when AWS lambda request payload is greater 6MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

## Context

I am trying to access AWS lambda using an AWS HTTP gateway.  I am currently using AWS Lamda proxy.

I understand that the following request payload limits are in place.

- HTTP Gateway Payload limit = 10 MB
- Lambda Payload limit = 6 MB

## Problem

If the request payload size > 10 MB, the HTTP gateway returns a HTTP 413 status code and I can catch this to show valid error message in the client side.  All is good so far.

However, if the payload size > 6MB but < 10MB then lambda fails since 6MB limit is exceeded by the request. In this case, the HTTP client receives a 500 HTTP error code and not a 413 as one could expect.

## Question

Is there any way to customize the HTTP response when lambda's 6MB request payload limit is hit?

Answer (score 0):

You can [handle Lambda errors in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html), mapping the standard Lambda error to a method response, where you can configure an HTTP status code for a given Lambda error.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention in my question that i am using `LAMBDA_PROXY` Just edited the question to add that.  Is there a way to map the lambda proxy response too?

Comment: I’m not sure about the Lambda Proxy integration, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using presigned urls? This way you avoid the payload limits but code changes are required on both client and server side, although should be small changes. The idea is that the client sends an http GET request to the API triggering the lambda, a presigned url is generated by the lambda and returned to the client and finally the client uploads directly to s3, circumventing lambda payload limits

But I think I might not be understanding your requirements..

Comment: My use case is not just an upload. I need to take a couple of files, process them and send the response back in the very same http request. So the S3 route won't work for me

Comment: I see. Could you not try and break your single http post into multiple https requests?

Comment: No.. the use case requires absolutely one http(s) request

Comment: Perhaps then you should consider adding compression to your response. Gzip might help: https://techblog.commercetools.com/gzip-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-5170bb02b543

Comment: thanks for the suggestion :) But my response is a application/json hardly spanning a few bytes. My request is heavy

Comment: Out of curiosity what is it that makes the payload so large, what is you request? A couple of files as you mentioned 4 comments ago? If that is the case, couldn't you just have these files persisted somewhere (S3?) or NFS or even EFS (elastic file storage for Lambdas) and then in your request, rather than passing the entire byte content, just pass the location of these files in the request? Then process them in your Lambda based on the location passed and finally send the http response back. All with 1 http request/response. Btw what does the response look like?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could control that quota too, but it doesn't look allowing that.

**Invocation payload (request and response)**

1. **6 MB** (synchronous)
2. 256 KB (asynchronous)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Otherwise, you may could **return your Lambda body as gzipped**.

```
const zlib = require('zlib')

zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify({
  ...
}), function (error, gzippedJSON) {
  if (error) context.fail(error)
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
    },
    body: gzippedJSON.toString('base64')
  }
  context.succeed(response)
})
```

But in this case, you should change your API Gateway's settings little bit.

Please refer this. https://medium.com/@janrubio/api-gateway-lambda-compression-86f61deed6a5